# Holomorphic functions with same restrictions on $\mathbb{R}$ - Paley-Wiener's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

The Theorem has two statements; the first one says that (proved):

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ is such that $f\in C(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and $Support(\hat{f})\subset[-\sigma,\sigma],$ then $\tilde f(x+iy):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\hat{f}(\lambda)e^{i\lambda(x+iy)}d\lambda$ $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ is an holomorpic extension of $f$ and $|\tilde f(x+iy)|\leq C e^{\sigma |y|}$ with $C$ and $\sigma>0$.

The second one says that ( to prove):

If $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is such that it is holomorphic, $|f(x+iy)|\leq C e^{\sigma |y|}$ with $C$, $\sigma>0$ and $f|_{\mathbb{R}}\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ $\Rightarrow$

$f(x+iy)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\hat{f|_{\mathbb{R}}}(\lambda)e^{i\lambda(x+iy)}d\lambda$ a.e.$\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}.$

I know that $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\hat{f|_{\mathbb{R}}}(\lambda)e^{i\lambda(x)}d\lambda$ a.e. $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ by using the fact that $Support(\hat{f|_{\mathbb{R}}})\subset[-\sigma,\sigma]$ and the inverse Fourier transform for real variable function.

I think to prove the equality in $\mathbb{C}$ by showing that

$|f(x+iy)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\hat{f|_{\mathbb{R}}}(\lambda)e^{i\lambda(x+iy)}d\lambda|\leq  2\sigma C||f||_{2,{\mathbb{R}}}e^{\sigma|\rho|},$ $\forall x+iy\in B_{\mathbb{C}}(0,\rho)$

and using the Liouville's Theorem to obtain that by the boundedness, the holomorphic property and the fact that their restrictions to real numbers are the same function, then the two functions are equal in $B_{\mathbb{C}}(0,\rho)$, $\forall \rho>0$.
I'm not sure if that works; my skills in complex analysis are very poor.

Comment: @iftiben10 , please don't edit to add tags that are not correct. The functions tag is not merely for questions that have functions in them. You can see the tag description that it is for elementary questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I found the answer: the identity principle holomorphic functions says that except for the null function, a holomorphic function always has isolated zeroes.